# Dependency issues while installing nautilus-dropbox

Tags: 18.04, dropbox

I cannot install dropbox on Ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I run `sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox`, I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output of `apt-cache policy nautilus-dropbox`:

```
nautilus-dropbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2019.02.14
  Version table:
     2019.02.14 500
        500 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        500 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2015.10.28-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And I did not read it , I used this in teminal:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created `.dropbox-dist` folder:

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Output of `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

```
dropbox: locating interpreter
dropbox: logging to /tmp/dropbox-antifreeze-w9d19V
dropbox: initializing
dropbox: initializing python 3.7.2
dropbox: setting program path '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/dropbox'
dropbox: setting home path '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155'
dropbox: setting python path '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155:/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/python-packages-37.zip'
dropbox: python initialized
dropbox: running dropbox
dropbox: setting args
dropbox: applying overrides
dropbox: running main script
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/psutil._psutil_linux.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/psutil._psutil_posix.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/linuxffi.pthread._linuxffi_pthread.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/cpuid.compiled._cpuid.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/apex._apex.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/tornado.speedups.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/linuxffi.resolv.compiled._linuxffi_resolv.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/librsyncffi.compiled._librsyncffi.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/linuxffi.sys.compiled._linuxffi_sys.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/posixffi.libc._posixffi_libc.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/somlak/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/linuxffi.gnu.compiled._linuxffi_gnu.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7919, in main
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7843, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 942, in __init__
  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 147, in make_default_file_system
  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 99, in __init__
  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 118, in _initialize_classes
  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/sync_engine.pyc", line 276, in <module>
  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/thin_adapter/in_proc.pyc", line 98, in <module>
  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/wrapped_thin_client.pyc", line 26, in <module>
  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/thin_client/client.pyc", line 28, in <module>
  File "dropbox/foundation/metrics/amp/remote_sink.pyc", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
!! dropbox: fatal python exception:
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7919, in main\n', '  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7843, in main_startup\n', '  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 942, in __init__\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 147, in make_default_file_system\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 99, in __init__\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 118, in _initialize_classes\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/sync_engine.pyc", line 276, in <module>\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/thin_adapter/in_proc.pyc", line 98, in <module>\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/wrapped_thin_client.pyc", line 26, in <module>\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/thin_client/client.pyc", line 28, in <module>\n', '  File "dropbox/foundation/metrics/amp/remote_sink.pyc", line 10, in <module>\n', 'ImportError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n'] (error 3)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After I run

grep dropbox /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list:deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu bionic main grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list.save: Permission denied

Comment: I very sorry I just don't very understand of all this , I just try to do as i read on most website, maybe it got out of my hand.

Comment: I have installed Dropbox on tw separate 18.04 LTS machines directly from the Ubuntu Software Center without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: Hi Graham That what i do in the first place, but can't install it.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps mentioned in this link? https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-dropbox-ubuntu/

Comment: Yes, I do but it come out no same.

Comment: I had no Idea, which permission was denied. sorry my English are so bad.

Comment: Thank you to all of you for helping me out. I got my Dropbox working now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a reproducible issue on Xenial as well as Bionic. The package `dropbox` which is being provided by [Dropbox's repository](https://linux.dropbox.com/) has some weird dependency tree since output of `apt rdepends dropbox` is

```
dropbox
Reverse Depends:
  Conflicts: nautilus-dropbox
  Depends: nautilus-dropbox
```

Here dependency is also the conflicting package which I think is weird and needs to be corrected from Dropbox's end.

The package `nautilus-dropbox` is also available in Ubuntu's Multiverse repositories. So, I'd recommend you to remove Dropbox's repository.

First of all determine which file has Dropbox repository's entry using:

```
grep dropbox /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Edit that file with sudo privileges and some text editor, for example, `nano`, and put a `#` to comment the line. To edit run:

```
sudo nano /path/to/file
```

Update APT's cache and install nautilus-dropbox:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox
```

If you want to use Dropbox daemon, install missing library using

```
sudo apt-get install libatomic1
```